# Use a function within a function JavaScript

Tags: javascript

### I have kept below simply for context:

---

How could I make a function inside a function (without nesting or using variables)?

Example of what I want:

```
var openPage = 1
function pageGame()
{

}
function pageUpgrades()
{
    openPage = 2;
    do checkPage()
}
function pageStats()
{

}
function checkPage()
{
    if (openPage ==     1)
    {
        document.getElementById("game").className = "open";
        document.getElementById("upgrades").className = "";
        document.getElementById("stats").className = "";            
    }
    if (openPage ==     2)
    {
        document.getElementById("game").className = "";
        document.getElementById("upgrades").className = "open";
        document.getElementById("stats").className = "";    
    }
    if (openPage ==     3)
    {
        document.getElementById("game").className = "";
        document.getElementById("upgrades").className = "";
        document.getElementById("stats").className = "open";    
    }
}
```

I want the function "checkPage" to run when I tell it to in "pageUpgrades"

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find any answers anywhere.

Edit - Note: I did attempt to use a simple `checkPage()` (without the do)

---

### Edit 3.5 years later: Wow, I certainly regret this post.

Please do note, for future viewers, if you ever want to to run a function within a function in JavaScript, simply specify the function within your code. Functions are accessible from anywhere so once specified you can execute your function simply by calling it.

If your function has parameters, specify those else you simply need:
`function()`

It is good practice to use semicolons even when unnecessary, see the comments below this post for the confusion there.

Comment: Remove the do and it'll just be called... `checkPage();`

Comment: "*function inside a function without nesting*" does not make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: @JohnO'Mahoney I tried that, it hasn't been working.

Comment: Have you also tried adding a semicolon at the end?

Comment: @dimlucas the semicolon is not be necessary here.

Comment: @dimlucas Tried it just then, not working.

Comment: If you tried it without the `do`, there's something wrong elsewhere. For example, make sure that all the elements exist

Comment: @mmm Ok, thanks I will look through it now.

Comment: The problem has to be somewhere else, the code works fine (see  [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8ddnhas3/))

Comment: Also, did you open the console in your browser (press F12)? Any errors?

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot.... I was trying to test it without it fully complete, I was testing it with the wrong place having the onclick to initiate the functions.

Comment: Thanks and sorry guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you have the `do` keyword before the function call, but besides that, you are already calling the `checkPage` function from `pageUpgrades`.